# Sharepoint calendar view filtering with caml query

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Have a fun issue with sharepoint calendar view filtering.
That code works fine:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                using (SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Site.ID))
                {
                    using (SPWeb site = siteCollection.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                        SPView view = site.Lists["My Calendar"].Views["Calendar"];
                        view.Query = @"<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>ololo</Value></Eq></Where>";
                        view.Update();
                        site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                    }
                }
            });
```

But when I change query to

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                using (SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Site.ID))
                {
                    using (SPWeb site = siteCollection.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                        SPView view = site.Lists["My Calendar"].Views["Calendar"];
                        view.Query = @"<Where><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>ololo</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>trololo</Value></Eq></Or></Where>";
                        view.Update();
                        site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                    }
                }
            });
```

I get exception:

Input string was not in a correct format. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.]
   System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal) +10161091
   System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info) +207
   System.Convert.ToInt32(String value, IFormatProvider provider) +55
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.CreateSystemDateTimeFromXmlDataDateTimeFormat(String strDT, Boolean fPreserveMilliseconds) +174
   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.Calendar.SafeFieldAccessor.GetDateTimeFieldValue(SPItem item, String fieldName) +227
   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.Calendar.CalendarItemRetriever.b_*0(SPItem item) +24
   System.Linq.WhereListIterator`1.MoveNext() +288
   System.Linq.<ExceptIterator>d__92`1.MoveNext() +322
   System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source) +548
   System.Linq.d*_0.MoveNext() +164
   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.Calendar.CalendarItemRetriever.ConvertItemType(IEnumerable`1 items) +578
   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.Calendar.DefaultCalendarListAccessor.Retrieve(String selectedDate, String scope, Dictionary`2 entityInfo) +18
   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.Calendar.CalendarService.CreateStartupResponse(ICalendarAccessor accessor, Dictionary`2 parameters, String viewType, String selectedDate) +249
   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.WebControls.AjaxCalendarView.CreateStartupData(String viewType, String selectedDate) +462
   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.WebControls.AjaxCalendarView.CreateBodyOnLoadScript(SPWeb web) +306
   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.WebControls.AjaxCalendarView.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +425
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +108
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +224
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +224
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +224
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +224
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +224
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +224
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +224
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +224
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3394

Does anybody know how fix that problem?

Comment: A bit OT but why are you using RunWithElevatedPermissions? Its likely that you shouldn't be (unless you are deliberately bypassing security trimming) and even if you are - its not really relevant for this question so its confusing the code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved. "DateRangesOverlap" should be added to the calendar query.

```
view.Query = @"<Where><And><DateRangesOverlap>
    <FieldRef Name='EventDate' />
    <FieldRef Name='EndDate' />
    <FieldRef Name='RecurrenceID' />
    <Value Type='DateTime'><Month /></Value>
</DateRangesOverlap>
<Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title' />
<Value Type='Text'>orlolo</Value></Eq>
<Eq><FieldRef Name='Title' />
<Value Type='Text'>trololo</Value></Eq>
</Or></And></Where>";
```

Comment: I too had noticed this when recreating this on my dev VM - however it worked for me without the DateRangesOverlap nodes. If it works for you though, that's cool.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the item with the Title "trololo" isn't "trolling" your page and breaking it (probably due to invalid data)?

See if you can manually create that view in the UI, then write a console app to go in there and print out what it generates for the Query. I just did and the query was syntactically identical to your example.

Comment: The problem occures only when I add second condition to the query. With only one condition query works fine with any title.